# How can I increase the speed of string generating in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

By searching I could find the following solution to generate all the combination of a given string and calculate their hash values. Now I can  generate 10000000 strings and hash values in 21 seconds. However, I need a faster method.

```
import itertools
import hashlib
import time

def pow():
    global cnt
    authdata = "eTSlASZYlLNgKJuYeIQvGVbiAcLEEOVgAQPzSrtCOIwQxQHyFHcfjgRQJBJDlojx";
    l = 'abcdefghij'
    result = itertools.product(*([l] * 7))
    for each in result:
        cnt = cnt + 1
        suffix = ''.join(each)
        authdataSuffix = authdata + suffix
        hashValue = hashlib.sha1(authdataSuffix.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if  hashValue.startswith("0"*8):    
            print (hashValue)


cnt = 0
start = time.time() 
pow()
end = time.time()
print(cnt)
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Use another programming language that supports multithreading? :-)

Comment: Python does support multithreading

Comment: python support it and I have checked both multiprocessing and multi threading which makes it faster. The thing is first I wan to make the individual version faster and then also use multiprocessing.

Comment: @Bamshad you are using hashlib functions here. Very little you can do to speed this up further without rewriting the library. The other operations like addition are very cheap. So you options are a) use a ProcessPool b) Use Cython c) Get a faster computer

Comment: You could gain a bit more speed if you don't use a for loop

Comment: d) maybe use C++, I should check them all

Comment: C++ will be faster

Comment: Yes with C++ I could build the same amount (10000000) within 6 seconds. But, using multiprocessing or another language is not the answer of my question. I wan to make this code faster and then however I will use multiprocessing later.

Comment: I recommend to use 'timeit' to get more reliable results.

Comment: And, as per my earlier comment, I don't think that that is possible. There is nothing in here that isn't either trivial, or a library function.

Comment: You could see if Numba is able to JIT the code into a faster form, but I strongly suspect it can't do much.

Comment: Also, you can eke out a tiny bit more speed by making "00000000" a constant.

Comment: I don't beleive this will make significant improvements, but instead of using `cnt`, you could simply use `len(result)` if you don't need the value of `cnt` inside your loop. You would save one line per loop.

Comment: What about using [Pypy](http://pypy.org/) instead of CPython? Would it be an option?

Comment: Currently I am working on other options but pypy is new to me. I should check it that as well. btw, so far the only thing that really work is C++

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading or multi-processing would be the best way to speed up your program other than changing over to a faster language like `C++`

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks for improvements:

- Do not use `global` variables
- Use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for meaningful measurements
- Use Python 3
- I think you can use [`permutations` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutation), which is faster in generating, but also produces less data
- Make everything possible constant